# How to set exact time for splash screen with loading on launch in iPhone query?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, splash-screen

In my Map application I have called web service method in ViewDidLoad method. Therefore my 
splash screen displays for longer time (more than 5sec) if network is poor to load web service data on my first screen MapView.

I want to show Default.png just for 3sec and then my first screen with loading indicator like
recent facebook application on iPHone. What is the logic behind the app. I tried many things but no success yet. Thanks in advance.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2254351/iphone-splash-screen

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
You will need to use performSelector: withDelay: method and provide the delay to 3-4 seconds, whatever is desired. NSTimer will also work but perfomSelector is a more lighter approach.

Try using it in the function where you allocate the splash image. In this case as u said u need to call from ViewDidLoad another function something like performSelector:removeSplashScreen and put this in [self performSelector:removeSplashScreen afterDelay:4 withObject:imgSplash];

THis will call the removeSplashScreen after 4 seconds and hence pass the splash image as parameter to this function.
 Inside removeSplashScreen do something like this:
-(void)removeSplashScreen:(UIImageView*)imgSplash {

//remove splash hence 4 seconds have passed.
[imgSplash removeFromSupreview];
[imgSplash release];

//After this allocate UIActivityIndicator view or whatever custom view for further loading
//You can also call an NSURLConnection here for the data parsing as the splash has been //removed thereby showing an activity to user.

}

//hope this helps :)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use NSTimer for this functionality.

Answer (score 0):

In that first of all u put the default.png then

Adding the simple viewcontroller like below code then

```
[window addSubview:viewController.view];
```

In that you can be adding the Activitiy Indicator to put.

and then the when the Internet connection finish then following delegate method to call

```
-(void)ShowTabAbout{
    [viewController.view removeFromSuperview];  
    self.imgV.frame=CGRectMake(0, 425, 320, 55);
    self.imgV.image=[UIImage imageNamed:@"tBar5.png"];
    [self.tabctr.view addSubview:self.imgV];
    self.tabctr.selectedIndex=4;
    [self animationTabCode];
    [window addSubview:tabctr.view];
}
```

Belowing is the code for the animation

```
-(void)animationTabCode{
    CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
    [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:context];
    [UIView setAnimationTransition: UIViewAnimationTransitionFlipFromRight forView:self.window cache:YES];
    [UIView setAnimationCurve:UIViewAnimationCurveEaseInOut];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:0.5];
    [UIView commitAnimations];
}
```

This type you can create the application like wise

Comment: Thanks for the answer..I will surly try If I get time. Right now I used performSelector method with timedelay